# infinitive phrase function question

Tags: infinitives

Macron beat far-right candidate Marine Le Pen **to become** France's youngest-ever president.

in this sentence

I am confused with its function, to become.

Is it used as an adverb? adjective? noun?

can you give me more examples like this?

Answer (score 1):

"to become" is the [infinitive](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/infinitive.htm) in the [infinitive phrase](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/infinitivephrase.htm). A infinitive is made up of the word "to" and simple verb.

> Infinitives can be used as nouns, adjectives, or adverbs

and

> Infinitive phrases can function as nouns, adjectives, or adverbs

Examples (from the link):

As a noun:

> **To finish her shift without spilling another pizza into a customer's lap** is Michelle's only goal tonight.

As an adjective:

> The best way **to survive Dr. Peterson's boring history lectures** is a sharp pencil to stab in your thigh if you catch yourself drifting off.

As an adverb:

> Kelvin, an aspiring comic book artist, is taking Anatomy and Physiology this semester **to understand the interplay of muscle and bone in the human body**.